# F# generic function filter list of discriminated unions

Tags: generics, filter, f#, unions

F# newbie question.
I have a list of discriminated unions like:

```
type Type1 = { name:string;  id: int;  }
type Type2 = { x: float; y: float;}
type Type3 = { x: float; naam:string}
type Union1 =
    | T1 of Type1
    | T2 of Type2
    | T3 of Type3 
let lst1 = [ T1 {name="nnn";  id=3};  T2 {x=1.1; y=1.3}; T1 {name="naam1";  id=39}; T3{x=0.0; naam="xx"}]; 

//To filter out items of Type1, i do:
let fltT1 (l:list<Union1>) :list<Type1> =
    let rec loop (l:list<Union1>)  (acc:list<Type1>) =
        match l with
        | h::t -> match h with
                   // this is now specific per type
                   | T1{name=n;id=i} -> loop t ({name=n;id=i}::acc)
                   | _ -> loop t acc
        | [] -> acc
    loop l [] |> List.rev
```

How can I make such a function generic to specify in the call 
the required output type (Type1|Type2|Type3)?

Comment: Your issue has been resolved?

Answer (score 13):

My approach would probably be just to use `List.choose` or `Seq.choose`.  It has advantages over `filter/map` because you only need to perform the pattern match once and it's a  lot more concise than a `fold`.

```
lst1 
|> List.choose 
    (function
     |T1 res -> Some res
     |_ > None)
```

`choose` is something like a map and a filter combined, it returns `f(x)` for every element where that result was `Some` and ignores all elements where it was `None`.  In this example, the return type is a `Type1 list`.

---

Parametrising a function based on a particular union case is not possible, this is because particular union cases are not themselves types, they are merely constructors for the union type.  `T1` in your example is not a type but `Union1` is.  That means, at some point, an explicit pattern match is required to decompose it.  (Note that this isn't true of all functional languages, Scala's union cases are modelled with inheritance but F# adopts the approach used by the likes of Haskell, Ocaml, etc.).

As Fyodor Soikin mentioned, you can write a static member or a function to check against each case if you wish, as an example:

```
static member tryAssumeT1 = function 
    |T1 t1 -> Some t1
    | _ -> None
```

You can then use this syntax:

```
lst1 |> List.choose (tryAssumeT1)
```

Comment: Thanks, that's nice and short.
But It seems I still need to write separate expressions (functions) to filter out items for Type1 , Type2 and Type3 ?
Is it possible to create a parameterized function with the required type?

Comment: You can encode it nicely by providing accessor functions for your `Union1` type, like `static member t1 = function T1 t -> Some t | _ -> None` and then using them as argument to `List.choose` like `List.choose Union1.t1`.

Comment: That works!
But I first had to declare Type1 .. Type3 ,  
then the union constructors  T1 .. T3,  and only after that add the static
"matching" function to the type Type1 .. Type2.  
Is that correct?

Comment: @RobF I think the answer to your question is yes but I've updated my answer with an example of this sort of construction, that should hopefully serve as clarification.